# Detect multi touch capabilities android

Tags: android, multi-touch

Im currently working on a  game that uses multi touch to apply zoom to the camera but i i want to put a magnifying glass in those devices that does not have multi touch capabilities.

I've already searched and i cant find the answer,

thanks!

Comment: Are there really that many devices that don't support multi-touch that you need to code for them?

Comment: sorry i have to do it is not my choice

Comment: I understand, but to be honest, I can't remember ever seeing an android device without multi-touch. I really can't imagine that there are *any* active devices without it.

Comment: @WesleyWiser there is devices without multitouch, unfortunately (even now, at 10.2012). My boss have one :) If device doesn't support multitouch then you can display zoom buttons (at Google Map for example), so it's can be useful to know is device supporting multitouch or not.

Comment: I have an Android device that does not have multitouch, and I know of a number of others. So this is quite a meaningful question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH) what you're looking for:

```
if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH)) {
  //do multitouch
} else {
  //do magnifying glass
}
```

Comment: Great way to detect the system has multi touch capability. Is there a way to detect how many fingers are supported?